# Making select and delete queries as single statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, sql-delete

First query

```
    select id from posts where post_title='abc' || post_title='xyz' order by id desc limit 1;
```

Let's say the returned values are 730 and 735.

Next query

```
    delete from posts where id in(730,735);
```

I want both of these queries to be combined into one statement. How can it be done. Please help

I have tried this one below. it doesn't work.

```
delete from posts where id in
        (
            select id from posts where post_title='abc' order by id desc limit 1,
                            select id from posts where post_title='xyz' order by id desc limit 1
                        );
```

Comment: Any specific reason of using `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: i want to delete only one entry which is the id with higher value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM posts 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id 
             FROM (SELECT post_title, MAX(id) id 
                   FROM posts 
                   WHERE post_title IN ('abc', 'xyz') 
                   GROUP BY post_title 
                  ) A 
            )
```

**OR**

```
DELETE FROM posts 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id 
             FROM (SELECT post_title, id 
                   FROM posts 
                   WHERE post_title IN ('abc', 'xyz') 
                   ORDER BY post_title, id DESC
                 ) A 
            GROUP BY post_title)
```

Comment: i am trying to delete duplicate entries. so i want only one row returned with highest id per match.

Comment: @KrishGowda You will get latest(only one) entry of posts based on post title specified in where condition

Comment: @KrishGowda You're most welcome. You can also upvote any question and answer if you find that it is helpful to you by clicking on up arrow above the right mark

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, We must use **IF-EXISTS** clause when executing  delete-and-select in one query, because if select returns null, it will throw an exception so try this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT id FROM [Posts] WHERE post_title IN ('abc', 'xyz'))
BEGIN 
     DELETE FROM posts 
     WHERE id IN (SELECT id 
                  FROM [Posts]
                  WHERE post_title IN ('abc', 'xyz') 
                  ORDER BY post_title, id DESC
                 ) 
END
```

Comment: one up for the suggestion of using if exists. but i wanted only one row returned per one match of post_title value.

Comment: use MIN() and MAX() then, as @Saharsh suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
delete from posts where id in (
    select * from
    (
       select id from posts 
       where post_title='abc' or post_title='xyz'
    ) as t
);
```

You have to wrap it in an alias.

Comment: @KrishGowda I have updated the query above and have tested it too. Please try again.

Comment: i am trying to delete duplicate entries. so i want only one row returned with highest id per match.

Answer (score 0):

As a  solution to your problem please try executing following sql query

```
delete FROM `posts` WHERE  id in 
(select p.id from 
                 (select id from posts where title in('abc','xyz') p)
```

Comment: i am trying to delete duplicate entries. so i want only one row returned with highest id per match.

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

**In MySQL, you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part.**

If you absolutely need the subquery, there's a workaround, but it's ugly for several reasons, including performance:

```
delete from posts where id in
(
  select id from (select * from posts)as x 
  where post_title = 'xyz' or
        post_title = 'abc'
  order by id desc
);
```

see [here in action](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87db2/1)

just **add limit 1** in your actual code, not supported by the online version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM [posts]
WHERE id = ANY( SELECT id FROM [posts] WHERE post_title IN('abc','xyz') );
```